# How to create this react modal the right way?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have been working on my first Meteor application and am a bit stuck. I want to create my code following the latest guidelines (ES6 and React 15) but I am confused with all the recent changes in Javascript.

I want to add a Bootstrap Modal in my current comments list but can't seem to figure out how to add my content to the modal using the right up to date syntax.

Here is my current code:

In comment.js:

```html
import React from 'react';
import { Row, Col, ListGroupItem, FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Bert } from 'meteor/themeteorchef:bert';
import { CommentsModal } from './comments-modal'


export const Comment = ({ comment }) => (

  <ListGroupItem key={ comment._id }>
    <Row>
      <Col xs={ 8 } sm={ 10 }>
        <FormControl
          type="text"
          defaultValue={ comment.title }
        />
      </Col>
      <Col xs={ 4 } sm={ 2 }>
        <Button
          bsStyle="danger"
          className="btn-block">
          Remove Comment
        </Button>
      </Col>
    </Row>
    <CommentsModal/>
  </ListGroupItem>
);
```

In Comments-modal.js:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal, Button, Tooltip } from 'react-bootstrap';

export class CommentsModal extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false,
    };

    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
  }

  close() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }

  open() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          bsStyle="primary"
          bsSize="large"
          onClick={this.open}
        >
        </Button>

        <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title >Modal heading</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <h4>Text in a modal</h4>

          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And last comments-list.js:

```html
import React from 'react';
import { ListGroup, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Comment } from './comment';

    export const CommentsList = ({ comments }) => (
      comments.length > 0 ? <ListGroup className="comments-list">
        {comments.map((com) => (
          <Comment key={ com._id } comment={ com } />
        ))}
      </ListGroup> :
      <Alert bsStyle="warning">No comments yet. Please add some!</Alert>
    );

    CommentsList.propTypes = {
      comments: React.PropTypes.array,
    };
```

I manage to get the Modal to show up and work but when I want to display data in it, I can't get it to work. What is the best way to combine both these into one?

Comment: "What is the best way to combine both these into one?" Combine both of what into one? If I'm understanding right, you want to display CommentList within the Modal body?

Comment: Does it give any errors ? if it does, will you show it to us ?

Comment: " I want to display data in it, I can't get it to work" What data, from where, and where is it suppose to be rendered? Your modal code doesn't render anything except the `<h4>Text in a modal</h4>` ??? I see `comments-list` is suppose to be passed comments so I'm assuming that's what you're talking about but you're not using it in the modal? Can you clarify what exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: Sorry about not formulating my question the right way and thanks for pointing this out. So I actually managed to get the data I in the Modal as I wanted. I just needed to pass my variables into the <CommentsModal/>, which I forgot. Let me now reframe my question, is it possible to reformat my Comments-modal.js so it also becomes a statless functional component? If so, what would be the best way to do it. The "this." keeps messing me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to keep local state out of component when using redux if possible, so to answer your question on making it stateless, I would take the following steps:

- Remove the button that opens the modal from the modal.js itself
- Remove the actual modal from the modal.js, just put the modal content inside of there.
- Change the open modal button to hook into an action creator that sets a prop to open the modal and passes it's content (also set one to close it)

So that looks something like this

```
 <ListGroupItem key={ comment._id }>
<Row>
  <Col xs={ 8 } sm={ 10 }>
    <FormControl
      type="text"
      defaultValue={ comment.title }
    />
  </Col>
  <Col xs={ 4 } sm={ 2 }>
    <Button
      bsStyle="danger"
      className="btn-block">
      Remove Comment
    </Button>
  </Col>
</Row>

<!-- Here is where it changes, -->
 <Button
      bsStyle="primary"
      bsSize="large"
      onClick={this.props.openModal(comment)}
    >
    </Button>

    <Modal show={this.props.commentModal} onHide={this.props.closeModal}>
       <CommentsModal content={this.props.commentModal} />
    </Modal>
```

Keep in mind, these naming conventions are just for examples sake : use whatever works best for you.

So what happens here is when you click that button you fire `this.props.openModal` (an action) which does something like this in the reducers -

```
 case actions.OPEN_COMMENT_MODAL:
       return state.set('commentModal', action.content);
```

the close buttons fire the `onHide` which is linked to the `this.props.closeModal` action which just does:

```
case actions.OPEN_COMMENT_MODAL:
       return state.set('commentModal', undefined);
```

So what this allows you to do is have just 1 modal instance and you pass the current comment to it with that button click and open it. The show just checks the truthy value, so you set it back to undefined and it will hide itself.

Then I am passing the prop of `content` to the modal, so you can then use it inside the modal itself. Again, change the names to whatever works best for you.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation, I am going to try it out!

Comment: @Deelux great, let me know if you have any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the data in props to the CommentsModal and render it as you would normally do.

Comment: Indeed, this I forget. Thanks